# Using Team City with NAnt for .NET

Tags: continuous-integration, teamcity, nant

I am starting to use Team City, I would like to add NAnt to build my .NET projects and also a way to run sql files from a folder. What is the best way to achieve this and is there a tutorial for this?, or what is the best way to do this?. I checked on google but I quite do not understand the process or where to start. I have team city installed and nant. If anyone could point me in the right direction I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Teamcity comes with a NAnt runner: http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD8/NAnt

The best way to make it work is:
- build your own script 
- test it on your own machine, without teamcity
- commit the script into source control 
- configure teamcity to run it using the NAnt runner

this way in case of future troubles you can always debug your script locally.

Hope it helps.